# Get Kuberbetes Pod name id as an environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am trying to get the id in the pod name as a environment variable in the yaml file:

```
job-05d93d91-d527-4b06-ad89-593f0350ecd6-jobmanager--1-qfjqf      1/1     Running   0          22m
job-05d93d91-d527-4b06-ad89-593f0350ecd6-taskmanager-66758j5h4d   1/1     Running   0          22m
job-05d93d91-d527-4b06-ad89-593f0350ecd6-taskmanager-66758vsj5q   1/1     Running   0          22m
```

I want to have "66758vsj5q" and "66758j5h4d" and "qfjqf" as an env variable.

I am able to get the pod name by exposing:

```
 envVars:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
```

but POD_NAME from [Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) returns the whole pod name. I am actually using ververica platform and following [this documentation](https://docs.ververica.com/user_guide/application_operations/deployments/kubernetes.html#environment-variables).

Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 2):

Below are the supported things that you could get with `valueFrom`.

> valueFrom: Source for the environment variable's value. Cannot be used if value is not empty.
>
> EnvVarSource represents a source for the value of an EnvVar.
>
> **configMapKeyRef** (object)
>
> Selects a key of a ConfigMap.
>
> **fieldRef** (object)
>
> Selects a field of the pod: supports metadata.name, metadata.namespace, metadata.labels, metadata.annotations, spec.nodeName, spec.serviceAccountName, status.hostIP, status.podIP.
>
> **resourceFieldRef** (object)
>
> Selects a resource of the container: only resources limits and requests (limits.cpu, limits.memory, limits.ephemeral-storage, requests.cpu, requests.memory and requests.ephemeral-storage) are currently supported.
>
> **secretKeyRef** (object)
>
> Selects a key of a secret in the pod's namespace

So the way you are trying, it does not work.

The string you are getting from `metadata.name` is actually already exposed as environment variable with name `HOSTNAME`.

Knowing the pattern of those names, *name-hash* you can use shell, or any other tool to get the last part. For example, by parameter expansion or by splitting on the hyphen. It would depend on which context you want to use that value.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: get-hash
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: get-hash
          image: busybox
          command: ["sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - |
              echo "the podname is: $HOSTNAME";
              echo "the hash is: ${HOSTNAME##*-}"
```

```sh
$ kubectl create -f get-hash.yaml
$ kubectl logs job.batch/get-hash
the podname is: get-hash-mpf7p
the hash is: mpf7p
```

Comment: Is there any piece of documentation that mentions explicitly that HOSTNAME environment variable is always set? In other words, is this a Kube-provider-specific behavior or it's part of some general spec?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment/ only mentions `hostname` command and `gethostname` function call in libc, but no environment variables.

Comment: @wheleph, the docs you link imply this variable on linux system. Every machine has a hostname, and if you are on linux this hostname is exposed as environment variable. At least in every shell I have used so far. Since the docs state the pods hostname is the pods name, they implicitly state that on linux the HOSTNAME variable is the podname.

Comment: I don't think on Linux this hostname is exposed as environment variable. `HOSTNAME` is not an _environment_ variable in bash. More on this: https://superuser.com/a/1819366/2966. Also some shells like dash don't expose `HOSTNAME` at all.

Comment: @wheleph, I guess what I am saying is, that kubernetes doesnt do anything special regarding this variable. Kubernetes only sets the hostname. That the variable exists in pretty much every shell is just a "linux thing"

Comment: also keep in mind I mention this variable regard to the extracting the hash from podname exposed via downward api. It is a shortcut in some situations, so you dont have to write the stuff to expose the variable. The real answer is trimming the value, no matter where you get it from. An alternative way to hostname is actually showcased in OPs question itself. The trimming can be applied to that the same way.